# Suppose a sequence ${x_n}$ converges. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{|x_n|} = \sqrt{|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n|}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

I have been manipulating the triangle inequality with the definition of a limit but cannot get a solid proof.

Comment: Same reason as in [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916000/suppose-a-seqence-x-n-converges-prove-that-lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9ex-n-lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9e). If $f$ is continuous and $x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} x$, then $f(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} f(x)$ (if everything if well-defined).

Answer (score 1):

It is already answered somewhere. It is just because the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$$
is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{m,n} = \sqrt{|(x_n)|}$ for all $m$.  And use information on this other site inside math stack exchange:  [When can you switch the order of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove it by definition. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim x_n=x$. We want to show that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n>n_0\Rightarrow|\sqrt{|x_n|}-\sqrt {|x|}|<\epsilon.$$

If $x=0$, since $\lim x_n=0$, then $\lim|x_n|=0$ and therefore there exists $n_0\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n>n_0\Rightarrow|x_n|<\epsilon^2,$$ and thus $$n>n_0\Rightarrow|\sqrt{|x_n|}|=\sqrt{|x_n|}<\epsilon.$$

Now, if $x\neq 0$, since $$||x_n|-|x||=|\sqrt {|x_n|}-\sqrt {|x|}||\sqrt {|x_n|}+\sqrt {|x|}|,$$ we have $$|\sqrt {|x_n|}-\sqrt {|x|}|=\frac{||x_n|-|x||}{|\sqrt {|x_n|}+\sqrt {|x|}|}.$$ 
Since $\lim x_n=x$, there exists $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n>n_1\Rightarrow|x_n-x|<\frac{|x|}{2},$$ and so, by triangle inequality, $$n>n_1\Rightarrow \frac{|x|}{2}=|x|-\frac{|x|}{2}<|x_n|.$$Hence $$n>n_1\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x_n|}}<\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}$$

Now, note that $\lim x_n=x$ implies $\lim|x_n|=|x|$ (the converse isn't true!), so there exists also $n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n>n_2\Rightarrow||x_n|-|x||<\epsilon(\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}+\sqrt{|x|}).$$
Finally, take $n_3=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. We conclude that $$n>n_3\Rightarrow|\sqrt{|x_n|}-\sqrt {|x|}|<\epsilon.$$